# How to iterate through a bunch of values in a dictionaries that are lists python

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

```
ratinglist = open("ratings.txt").readlines()

booklist = open("booklist.txt").readlines()

keys = [key.strip('\n') for key in ratinglist[0::2]]

values = [value.strip(' \n').split(' ') for value in ratinglist[1::2]]


my_dict = dict(zip(keys, values))


for values in my_dict:
    value * x = sum
```

So, I have a giant dictionary that has a list of values for each key.

Here is an example of my dictionary:

```
'KeeLed': ['0', '0', '0', '5', '0', '0', '0', '5', '0', '5', '5', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '5', '-3', '-3', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '5', '0', '0', '5', '0', '5', '5', '5', '5', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '3', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0'], 'Megan': ['5', '5', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '3', '0', '5', '0', '0', '1', '0', '5', '0', '1', '5', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '5', '0', '0', '3', '5', '5', '0', '0', '5', '0', '0', '3', '0', '0', '3', '5', '5', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '5', '5', '0', '5', '0', '0']}
```

What I need to do is do a for loop, that loops through each value, multiplies them, and then adds them.

I just need help getting the for loop to iterate through the values correctly.

For example, for KeeLed and Megan, I want this for loop to iterate through their seperate lists of values, and multiply them, then add them.

Like this: 0 * 5, + 5 * 0, + 0 * 0, + 5 * 0.... etc etc

The issue is I haven't found anything online on how to iterate through lists that are inside a **dictionary** . I've found some resources on looping through lists, but I need to loop through lists of values that are inside of a dictionary.

I would like the results to be put in a list, but I could do that if I get some help with the for loop.

```
scores for each person = [325, 450]
```

Comment: if I understand correctly, for a list `[1, 2, 3, 4]` you want : `output = 1*2 + 3*4 = 14` ?

Comment: You won't get a tutorial on every combination of capabilities.  The fact that the list is a dict value is immaterial: you know how to get a value from a dict; you know how to iterate through a list.  Put those together in that order.

Answer (score 0):

**"The issue is I haven't found anything online on how to iterate through lists that are inside a dictionary . I've found some resources on looping through lists, but I need to loop through lists of values that are inside of a dictionary."**

**EXAMPLE**

```
myDict = {

'KeeLed': ['0', '0', '0', '5', '0', '0', '0', '5', '0', '5', '5', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '5', '-3', '-3', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '5', '0', '0', '5', '0', '5', '5', '5', '5', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '3', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0'], 
'Megan': ['5', '5', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '3', '0', '5', '0', '0', '1', '0', '5', '0', '1', '5', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '5', '0', '0', '3', '5', '5', '0', '0', '5', '0', '0', '3', '0', '0', '3', '5', '5', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '5', '5', '0', '5', '0', '0']

}

# For-looping through dict will give the key.
for name in myDict:

  total = 0

  # applying the key into myDict will give the list associated with the dict
  for score in myDict[name]:

    total = total + int(score)

  print(name,total)
```

**Result**

```
KeeLed 54
Megan 85
```